# Not able to process [GET] response in swagger ui

Tags: node.js, express, get, swagger-ui

Other than GET all APIs work seamlessly. The problem i am not able to figure out please help me in getting this through.

```
      /**
         * @swagger
         * /admin/get_all_languages:
         *   get:
         *     produces:
         *       - application/json
         *     summary: Get all languages.
         *     description:  This API fetches all the languages.
         *     tags:
         *       - Admin
         *     security:
         *       - JWTAuth: []  # Specify JWT as the authentication method
         *     responses:
         *       '200':
         *         description: Successful response - Fetched all languages successfully.
         *         content:
         *           application/json:
         *             schema:
         *               type: array  # Adjust this based on the actual response structure
         *       '401':
         *         description: Unauthorized. JWT token is missing or invalid.
         *       '500':
         *         description: Internal server error.
         */
        this.router.route('/get_all_languages').get(AuthService.authenticateToken, AdminController.getAllLanguages);
```

when i hit this i get this error

error: ::1 HTTP/1.1 500 GET /api/v1/admin/get_role_for_assigning - Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of undefined (#unknown) :
ServerError: Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of undefined
at Function.get

this is how cors has been handled

```
private options: Record<string, unknown> = {
    cors: {
      origin: (origin: string, callback: ( error: Error, status?: boolean ) => void) => {
        // origin = origin.trim(); // to remove extra space 
        console.log("Request Origin",origin)
        if (AUTHORIZED.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
          // if (authorizedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
          callback(null, true);                                              
        } else {
          callback( notAcceptable('Domain not allowed by CORS') );
        }
      },
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
      allowedHeaders: ['Accept', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'From'],
      credentials: true,
    },
```

Swagger Options file

```
const swaggerOptions = {
      definition: {
        openapi: '3.0.0',
        info: {
          title: 'Nitin API',
          version: '1.0.0',
          description: 'NITIN API Documentation'
        },
        servers: [
          {
              url: 'http://localhost:8101/api/v1',
              description: 'Local server'
          },
          {
              url: 'https://vtt.myclient.com/api/v1',
              description: 'DEV Env'
          }
        ],
        components: {
          securitySchemes: {
            JWTAuth: { // Define the Bearer Token (JWT) security scheme
              type: 'http',
              scheme: 'bearer',
              bearerFormat: 'JWT',
            }
          }
        },
        security: [{
          JWTAuth: []
        }]
      },
      apis: ['src/api/core/routes/v1/*.ts'],
      // apis: ['../core/routes/v1/*.ts']
    };

    const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsdoc(swaggerOptions);
    // console.log("swaggerSpec", swaggerSpec);
    const excludeSwagger = true;

    if(excludeSwagger){
      // this.application.use('/api-docs', (req, res, next) => {
      //   req.headers['Content-Type'] = CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['application/json'];
      //   next();
      // });
      this.application.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
    }
```

the part where i might be getting this error

```
validate(req: Request, res: Response, next: (e?: Error) => void): void {

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin'],
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
      });
      res.end();
      return ;
    }

    if (!req.headers['content-type']) {
      return next( notAcceptable(`Content-Type headers must be ${CONTENT_TYPE} or 'multipart/form-data', ${req.headers['content-type']} given`) );
    }

    const contentType = req.headers['content-type'];

    if (['PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT'].includes(req.method)) {
      if(CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['text/plain'] === req.headers['content-type']) {
        console.log('second')
        return next( notAcceptable(`Content-Type headers must be ${CONTENT_TYPE} or 'multipart/form-data', ${req.headers['content-type']} given`) );
      }
    }

    if ( CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM[CONTENT_TYPE] !== req.headers['content-type'] && req.headers['content-type'].lastIndexOf(CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['multipart/form-data']) === -1 && CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['text/plain'] !== req.headers['content-type'] && CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['application/json; charset=utf-8'] !== req.headers['content-type']){
      console.log('third')
      console.log('req.headers', req.headers['content-type'])
      // if(req.headers['content-type'] === 'text/plain'){
      //   console.log('fourth')
      // }
      return next( notAcceptable(`Content-Type head must be ${CONTENT_TYPE}, multipart/form-data or application/json; charset=utf-8, but ${req.headers['content-type']} given`) );
    }

 if (!req.headers.origin) {
      return next( notAcceptable('Origin header must be specified') );
    }
```

I tried to remove Headers hoping to resolve to something but didn't work quite frustrating maybe i am not able to get to the point which might be causing this issue.

```
if(req.method === 'GET'){
      delete req.headers['content-type']
    }

    if (
      req.headers['content-type'] &&
      CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM[CONTENT_TYPE] !== req.headers['content-type'] &&
      req.headers['content-type'].lastIndexOf(CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['multipart/form-data']) === -1 &&
      CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['text/plain'] !== req.headers['content-type'] &&
      CONTENT_TYPE_ENUM['application/json; charset=utf-8'] !== req.headers['content-type']
    ) {
      console.log('third')
      console.log('req.headers', req.headers['content-type'])
      return next( notAcceptable(`Content-Type head must be ${CONTENT_TYPE}, multipart/form-data or application/json; charset=utf-8, but ${req.headers['content-type']} given`) );
    }
```

Please ignore if i have done something stupid any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be stuck on GET request you are trying to delete the headers but it won't help instead try to look for request method GET and put a condition to check if the headers don't receive content type application json then assign

```js
req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
```

this should solve your error.